# LINQ projection that pairs items and fills with null when nth item doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The operation I would like to implement using LINQ should pair each nth element of both arrays. When one nth item doesn't exist, `null` is taken. Please, notice that arrays may have different lengths.

For example, if I have

- `a => {1, 2, 3, 4 }`
- `b => {0, 2, 0 }`
- `result => { {1,0}, {2,2}, {3,0}, {4, null} }`

If I had `a` and `b` inverted, I should obtain:

- `a => {0, 2, 0 }`
- `b => {1, 2, 3, 4 }`
- `result => { {0,1}, {2,2}, {0,3}, {null, 4} }`

I have thought of a combination of `Zip` and `DefaultIfEmpty`, but it only works in one direction :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length)).
  Select(x => new Tuple<int,int>( 
                        x<a.Length?a[x]:null,
                        x<b.Length?b[x]:null)
        ).ToArray();
```

Or if you don't want the resulting array's elements to be of type `Tuple`:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length)).
  Select(x => new { 
                        x<a.Length?a[x]:null,
                        x<b.Length?b[x]:null
                  }
        ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Range should starts from 0

Comment: And also, it is better to use Length in Math.Max, since original question was about arrays